# Graph in react with reccharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-native, recharts

I'm putting together some panels using the reacharts library, my array that contains all the json is the accounts array, which lists all the accounts that I have within the database.
the account array for example comes with the following fields.

Zip code

"SP"
City

"Sao Paulo"

statusAccount

"Side dish"
type

"Prospectus"

For example, I wanted to assemble a graph sorted by the "Type" field, for example, I have several types within the company, prospect, contract, among others.
Is there any function that can return me like this there are 100 prospect companies, there are 200 with type equal to contract, and so on?

For example, I would like my X axis to show my company types, on the Y axis side it could be a column of company numbers by type.
My API is in laravel, it is correctly returning my accounts in json

```
import React from "react";
import {
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer,
} from "recharts";

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/api";

function PanelAdmin() {
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllAccounts();
  }, []);

  const getAllAccounts = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}/accounts`);
    setAccounts(response.data);
  };

  // console.log(accounts);
  return (
    <div>
      <LineChart
        width={1000}
        height={400}
        data={accounts}
        margin={{ top: 5, right: 20, left: 10, bottom: 5 }}
      >
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <Tooltip />
        <CartesianGrid stroke="#f5f5f5" />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="id" stroke="#ff7300" yAxisId={0} />
        <Line type="monotone" dataKey="nome" stroke="#387908" yAxisId={1} />
      </LineChart>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PanelAdmin;
```

Comment: why u have this variable? `const endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/api";`. and if u r in prod?

Comment: My project is still running on friendly localhost

Comment: so will always be run in localhost? if yes, keep that `const endpoint` var, else, remove that. use it like this - `axios.get('/api/accounts')`

Comment: Friend, my API also runs on localhost, I put it this way that you passed there axios.get('/api/accounts')
does not work

Comment: what errors r u getting if u do it like that?

Comment: I have two API folders where my laravel project is and client where the react that consumes my api is when I give a php crafter serve and start laravel it runs on (http://localhost:8000/api)

it is giving the following error:
GET http://localhost:5173/api/accounts 404 (not found)

I think that's why my get had to be on the laravel endpoint

Comment: okay, so use the hardcoded endpoint, but when u build for prod u'll have to remember to change that across all the files